# python sqlAlchemy: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError when I change the class location

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I use sqlAlchemy to read data from mysql DB, it work when my class and the search code are in the same py file just like this:

```
class odd_basis(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'odd_basis'

    NO = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    LEAGUE = Column(String(20))
    TIME   = Column(String(20))

engine = create_engine("......")
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
DBsession = session()
basis_data = DBsession.query(odd_basis).filter(odd_basis.NO=='16039').all()
```

when I put the class definition in another py file, then use the sys.path.append to import, then it will have this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type  instead

my main code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("~/analysis/table_class.py")
engine = create_engine("......")
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
DBsession = session()
basis_data = DBsession.query(odd_basis).filter(odd_basis.NO=='16039').all()
```

table_class.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint, Index


Base = declarative_base()
class odd_basis(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'odd_basis'

    NO = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    LEAGUE = Column(String(20))
    TIME   = Column(String(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sys.path.append does not import anything. It just adds to your search path. You need to import your class from there:

```
from table_class import odd_basis
```

and so forth.

Hannu

Comment: Thanks, I try to add this code, but it have another error:  ImportError: No module named 'table_class'.

Comment: Even if I didn't add this import code, I instance the class, it work. I can use this code: lv2 = odd_basis(NO=1,LEAGUE="USA")  but it just can use the sqlAlchemy to fetch the DB.

Comment: You need to add the path to your table class without the filename. Also, 
~ does not work as such in Python. Try replacing your sys.path.append with  the whole path. You can also do  "from os.path import expanduser" and then sys.path.append(expanduser("~/analysis")).  Please note you need the directory in sys.path.append, not the filename itself. This allows you to import anything from that directory.  --Hannu